# Nested arrays using Any/AnyObject

Tags: arrays, swift

According to Apple's official book "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1)":

> - AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.
> - Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

Knowing that, I wanted to emulate Python-like nested list using an `Any` array.

```
let array = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6, [7, 8]], 1]
```

Since `Int` and `Array` are value types, I supposed that `array` would be typed as `[Any]`

But this wasn't the case here :

```
func flatten(list:[Any]) -> [Any] {
    var new = [Any]()
    for element in list {
        if let array = element as? [Any] {
            // this code never runs
            let flattened = flatten(array)
            for x in flattened {
                new.append(y)
            }
        }else{
            new.append(element)
        }
    }
    return new
}
```

*Note:* calling this function gave me `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error at first until I did this tweak :

```
let array : [Any] = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6, [7, 8]], 1]

Output :   [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6, [7, 8]], 1]
Expected : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
```

### Unexplained Solution:

I replaced everywhere in this example `Any` by `AnyObject`

Numbers now are of type `NSNumber`

```
func flatten(list:[AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject] {
    var new = [AnyObject]()
    for element in list {
        if let array = element as? [AnyObject] {
            let flattened = flatten(array)
            for x in flattened {
                new.append(y)
            }
        }else{
            new.append(element)
        }
    }
    return new
}

Output :   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
Expected : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
```

### Question :

Why is it working with `[AnyObject]` / `NSArray` and not with `[Any]`, despite the fact that integer literals are mainly of type `Int` not `NSNumber` and array literals are of type `Array` and not `NSArray`? *Is something wrong with my example?*

Comment: As an aside: I think that the fact that this crashed is a Swift bug. In Swift 3.0-dev it's different -- the declaration `let arr: [Any] = [1, [2, [3]]]` is refused by the compiler with `error: contextual type 'protocol<>' cannot be used with array literal`, so you can't even get that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Any`, Swift will wrap your nested array elements into NSArray and not into Swift arrays (which can't hold all Objective-C types). So your test `if let array = element as? [Any] {` will not be true if you use `Any` because the resulting array isn't of type `[Any]` but `NSArray`.

So if you want a function that manages `Any` you can change your test for:

`if let nestedArray = element as? NSArray {`

You then have to define a new `flattenArray()` function with an NSArray prototype:

```
func flattenArray(array: NSArray) -> [Any] {

    var flattenedArray: [Any] = []

    for element in array {

        // We have an array
        if let nestedArray = element as? NSArray {
            flattenedArray = flattenedArray + flattenArray(nestedArray)
        } else {
            // We have a single element
            flattenedArray.append(element)
        }
    }

    return flattenedArray
}

func flattenArray(array: [Any]) -> [Any] {

    var flattenedArray: [Any] = []

    for element in array {

        // We have an array
        if let nestedArray = element as? NSArray {
            flattenedArray = flattenedArray + flattenArray(nestedArray)
        } else {
            // We have a single element
            flattenedArray.append(element)
        }
    }

    return flattenedArray
}
```

and it will do the trick.

We could probably imagine a more elegant solution but with this example you get the idea behind this issue.

Comment: Is there a reason for Swift to wrap inner arrays into a NSArray object and not an array struct ?

Comment: Probably because Swift Array struct can't hold some Objective-C types. By specifying `Any` you allow Objective-C types to be in your `[Any]` array. `AnyObject` ensures that you have only objects so they can be wrapped into native struct Array.